# What language would provide stable processing of millions of dirty addresses into standardized format?

Tags: nlp, data-processing

I'm currently using NodeJS to create a program that takes uncleaned, mistyped, dirty addresses and convert them into standardized formats with all components found or filled in, for further use in digital use cases (such as a computer being capable of recognizing all the addresses, which is improbable given how dirty they can all be)

However I've finally hit the limit of NodeJS capabilities for this execution I feel, mainly in the fact of there's so much data that it either takes hours to run or multithreading is unstable and crashes constantly, and so I'd like to get pros and cons of other languages that might be good for use with this case

Answer (score 0):

I guess python will do the job